# Open PDF is not working in IE and safari using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, pdf, safari

I'm tried to load a `PDF` files in browser while button click using `angularjs`. This is my code.

```
       $http.get('assets/mercury_doc.pdf',{responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).success(function(data){
            var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            window.open(fileURL,"_self");
        });
```

It's working fine in Chrome and firefox. But not working in IE and safari.

Comment: Which version of IE/Safari are you using for your tests ? You can see the browser compatibility of Blob [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: IE 11.0 and safari 5.1.7